Changing endpoint_configuration of an AWS Custom Domain in Terraform
I'm trying to write a terraform module that creates an API Gateway and an associated custom domain.
The module allows the consumer to specify an 'endpoint type' for the API Gateway (i.e. EDGE or REGIONAL).
It works great at first, but if the endpoint type is changed without first tearing everything down, things start to break.
I've whittled it down to a aws_api_gateway_domain_name resource being the issue.
I have the following configuration for this:
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "custom_domain" {
  domain_name     = local.custom_domain
  regional_certificate_arn = local.domain_type == "REGIONAL" ? aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert[0].arn : null
  certificate_arn = local.domain_type == "EDGE" ? aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert[0].arn : null

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = [local.domain_type]
  }

  security_policy = "TLS_1_2"

  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert,
    aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert,
    aws_route53_record.cert_validation_record,
    aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway,
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
}


The issue I run into here is, endpoint_configuration cannot be updated in-place, as AWS doesn't support op:replace functionality for this property as per their docs.
Resulting in this error:
│ Error: updating API Gateway Domain Name (mydomain.testdomain.xyz): operation error API Gateway: UpdateDomainName, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 29ec3dcd-25c3-40e0-9f3c-0671e1ad7497, BadRequestException: /endpointConfiguration/types/0 Invalid request input
│ 
│   with module.example_api.aws_api_gateway_domain_name.custom_domain[0],
│   on ../../../../../Git/terraform-example/domain.tf line 45, in resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "custom_domain":
│   45: resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "custom_domain" {

As a result of this, I've also tried creating a separate aws_api_gateway_domain_name.edge_custom_domain and aws_api_gateway_domain_name.regional_custom_domain resources, with the thinking that I can just tear down the custom domain and create a new one with the appropriate configuration. However, the issue with that is that I can't get Terraform to destroy the existing EDGE / REGIONAL domain before spinning up the new one.
For example, using the following resources:
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "edge_custom_domain" {
  count           = local.create_domain && local.domain_type == "EDGE" ? 1 : 0
  domain_name     = local.custom_domain
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert[0].arn

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["EDGE"]
  }

  security_policy = "TLS_1_2"

  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert,
    aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert,
    aws_route53_record.cert_validation_record,
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "regional_custom_domain" {
  count           = local.create_domain && local.domain_type == "REGIONAL" ? 1 : 0
  domain_name     = local.custom_domain
  regional_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert[0].arn

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }

  security_policy = "TLS_1_2"

  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert,
    aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert,
    aws_route53_record.cert_validation_record,
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
}

Gives me an error like the following:
module.example_api.aws_api_gateway_domain_name.edge_custom_domain[0]: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating API Gateway Domain Name (mydomain.testdomain.xyz): operation error API Gateway: CreateDomainName, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: cb120eb4-dbf0-4424-a218-6a7eab16b7f7, BadRequestException: The domain name you provided already exists.
│ 
│   with module.example_api.aws_api_gateway_domain_name.edge_custom_domain[0],
│   on ../../../../../Git/terraform-example/domain.tf line 1, in resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "edge_custom_domain":
│    1: resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "edge_custom_domain" {

My specific question is: is it actually possible to do what I'm trying to do?
Bonus question: is it possible to have
aws_api_gateway_domain_name.regional_custom_domain and aws_api_gateway_domain_name.edge_custom_domain depends_on each other without introducing a cycle? I'd like to express something like "wait for the other resource to be destroyed if it needs to be"
Alternatively, is it possible to update the endpoint_configuration in a terraform-esque-way? The API Gateway configuration suggests creating the new configuration set and then deleting the old one, though this doesn't seem possible with Terraform.

What about using the same resource for both flavours of aws_api_gateway_domain_name and configuring it differently with dynamic blocks?
E.g.:
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "custom_domain" {
  count           = local.create_domain ? 1 : 0
  domain_name     = local.custom_domain
  certificate_arn = local.domain_type == "EDGE" ?  aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert[0].arn : null
  regional_certificate_arn = local.domain_type == "REGIONAL" ? aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert[0].arn : null

  dynamic "endpoint_configuration" {
    for_each = local.domain_type == "EDGE" ? ["EDGE"] : ["REGIONAL"]
    content {
      types = endpoint_configuration.value
    }
  }

  security_policy = "TLS_1_2"

  depends_on = [
    # aws_acm_certificate.edge_domain_cert, # explicit dependency not needed
    # aws_acm_certificate.regional_domain_cert, # explicit dependency not needed
    aws_route53_record.cert_validation_record,
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
}

I don't have time to test the code above.
